# Cloud functions idempotency issue

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I've implemented the `context.eventId` but now I'm encountering the following issue. Obviously, I'm not expecting calls to be triggered in the same order, or even just once per action, but still, the same event happening 3 times 10 seconds apart seems quite bad.

1. First trigger at **17:07:33** (
2. Second trigger at **17:07:43** ( **10 seconds** later )
3. Third trigger at **17:07:54** ( **11 seconds** later )

Between the same event which triggered three times ( 10 seconds apart ) other transactions have happened as well, therefore, when it first triggered, it saved that `eventId` then it lost it, because another event happened. Then the same event triggered again, 10 seconds later, which obviously wasn't marked as duplicate given the `lastEventId` was already overwritten by the previous transactions ( which happened during those 10 seconds gap ).

How can this be possible ? How can we get around this ? It takes only ~ 150ms to process them so it's not a big functions file which needs a lot of time during cold boot. It has cached global variables ( firestore ), it has lazy loading for variables I use on certain functions. It's a light functions file, overall. Only 250 lines of code with 9 functions inside the same file.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Functions gives at-least-once guarantees for the execution of background functions.  This means that it's possible for a function to execute multiple times per event.  While it is not common, it is just the way that scalable systems deal with potential errors when multiple machines must coordinate and communicate asynchronously.

If repeating a function invocation for an event is problematic for your function, you need to code your function in a way that makes it idempotent.  You can [watch this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pwsy8XR7HNE) to understand a little bit more, and read the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/retries#make_retryable_background_functions_idempotent).

The overall problem that can't be avoided is call the [Two Generals problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals%27_Problem) in computer science.  You can read about that to better understand the bigger issue.  Basically, all the computer systems that operation Cloud Functions can't 100% reliably communicate with each other all the time (due to errors and lost data), so retries are essential to ensure that a function gets executed at least once, which is better than never at all.

Comment: Hi Doug! I completely understand your point. I was just trying to figure out how to deal with it because the `lastEventId` solution does not work, when there's such a big gap between two or more executions. That `eventId` would just get overwritten with the next event, by the time the second trigger of the first event would finish, it would still get processed, due to lastEventId not actually being the "last" anymore.

I ended up doing one more read operation in the transaction, marking the document itself as processed, rather than keeping one last event or caching it inside a global array